# 2D Array Declaration - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to declare a 2D array of integers in two steps?  I am having an issue with scope.  This is what I am trying to do:

```
//I know Java, so this is an example of what I am trying to replicate:

int Array[][];
Array = new int[10][10];
```

Now, in OBJ-C I want to do something similar, but I cant get the syntax right.  Right now I have it in one step, but I cannot use it outside of the If-Statement in which I currently have it:

```
int Array[10][10]; //This is based on an example I found online, but I need 
                   //to define the size on a seperate line than the allocation
```

Can anyone help me out with this?  I know its probably a more basic question, but you can't use the keyword "new" outside of a message (to my knowledge) and you cant send messages to ints.  :(

**EDIT 1:***

My problem is scope related.

```
//Declare Array Somehow
Array[][] //i know this isn't valid, but I need it without size

//if statement
if(condition)
Array[1][2]
else
Array[3][4]

//I need to access it outside of those IFs

//... later in code
Array[0][0] = 5;
```

Comment: You *shouldn't* use `new` at all in Objective-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my preferred way of creating a 2D array, if you know the size of one of the boundaries:

```
int (*myArray)[dim2];

myArray = calloc(dim1, sizeof(*myArray));
```

And it can be freed in one call:

```
free(myArray);
```

Unfortunately, one of the bounds MUST be fixed for this to work.

However, if you don't know either of the boundaries, this should work too:

```
static inline int **create2dArray(int w, int h)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(int) * 2 + w * sizeof(int *);
    int **arr = malloc(size);
    int *sizes = (int *) arr;
    sizes[0] = w;
    sizes[1] = h; 
    arr = (int **) (sizes + 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = calloc(h, sizeof(**arr));
    }

    return arr;
}

static inline void free2dArray(int **arr)
{
     int *sizes = (int *) arr;
     int w = sizes[-2];
     int h = sizes[-1];

     for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
         free(arr[i]);

     free(&sizes[-2]);
}
```

Comment: The first method worked for me.  (Lucky me had 1 fixed dimension!!)  Thanks so much!!

Comment: this is a beautiful solution to creating variable-size 2d arrays. do note that h is unused in free2dArray(•)

Answer (score 0):

The declaration you showed (e.g. `int Array[10][10];`) is OK, and will be valid for the scope it was declared to, if you do it in a class scope, then it will be valid for the whole class.

If the size of the array varies, either use dynamic allocation (e.g. `malloc` and friends) or use `NSMutableArray` (for non-primitive data types)

Comment: I need access to it outside of the scope.  The size of the array varies based on an If-Else statement set, but then I can't use the variable outside of whichever IF/Else is used.

Comment: I edited the main post to better describe my question, but I suppose I could use an NSMutableArray.  I am working solely with "int" values though, so I was trying to stick with primitive types so that I don't have to constantly send messages for [intValue] and such

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma You should NOT use a NSArray for storing integers, it's not intended for that. You should always stick to using C arrays for that kind of stuff, or a C++ vector / array.

Comment: That is what I assumed was best.  I just can't figure out a way to satisfy my situation with a primitive array.  I don't know the size of the array until the conditional IF statements, but I still need access to it outside of the IF statement scope.