# create to dimensional array of integer in objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsinteger

I want to implement thing like that but i get error in add because of id !!!

```
NSMutableArray *rgbarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSInteger rgb[3];
            const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(cgcolor);
            CGFloat cgred = components[0];
            CGFloat cggreen = components[1];
            CGFloat cgblue = components[2];
            rgb[0] = cgred;
            rgb[1] = cggreen;
            rgb[2] = cgblue;

            [rgbarray addObject:rgb];
```

i want to add rgb instead of id ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [2D Array Declaration - Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485521/2d-array-declaration-objective-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only add pointers to instances of objects into `NSMutableArray`

You can use a `NSDictionary` or create your own subclass of `NSObject` to wrap the 3 values.

```
NSDictionary * rgbDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:cgred], @"cgred", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:cggreen], @"cggreen", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:cgblue], @"cgblue", nil];

[rgbarray addObject:rgbDictionary];
```

To retrieve the values

```
NSDictionary * rgbDictionary = [rgbArray objectAtIndex:0];
CGFloat cgred = [[rgbDictionary objectForKey:@"cgred"] floatValue];
CGFloat cggreen = [[rgbDictionary objectForKey:@"cggreen"] floatValue];
CGFloat cgblue = [[rgbDictionary objectForKey:@"cgblue"] floatValue];
```

I would actually use the subclass approach. Since you were trying to code with a C array for your values, the `NSDictionary` approach will get you past the error.

Comment: You really should just be using a C-array here, as NSArray w/ NSNumbers are incredibly slow compared to a c array.

Comment: I got this error when i tried to retrieve them back 
Initializing 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') with an expression of incompatible type 'id';

Comment: @salamonti I had typed the code into the browser only. I forgot to access the `floatValue`.  Since we populated the `NSDictionary` with `NSNumber`s, you need to use the `floatValue` property to access the primitive float from the `NSNumber`

Comment: Is it require any import file ?

Comment: @salamonti the adjusted code doesn't require an import.  Using the method `floatValue` as a opposed to the property. It is easier to get it to compile