# How to produce 2 dimensional Array in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How do i produce a 2 dimensional NSMutable array as this:

Array:

```
=>[item1]=>[item1a,item1b,item1c...]
=>[item2]=>[item2a,item2b,item2c...]
...
=>[item10]=>[item10a,item10b,item10c...]
```

So far i've only been successful up to the [item1]=>[item1a,item1b,item1c...]

When i try to add more 2 dimensional array it keeps overriding the first row.

Comment: Stay tuned, some of the additions made to clang will allow some shorthand syntax for creating arrays that will make multi-dimensional arrays much easier. Syntax will look like `array = @[ @[ item1a, item1b ], @[ item2a, item2b ] ];`. This will probably be part of the next release of Xcode.

Comment: Just how many times will this question be asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485521/2d-array-declaration-objective-c/10485613#10485613

Comment: @Richard: The question you linked is not about `NSArray`s inside of `NSArray`s.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau it's about 2 dimensional arrays in objective-c. The answer can be used for objects as well.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Except there is no clear ownership of objects.

Comment: @dreamlax - Will it be announced? Where can i keep a look out for this?

Comment: @TeamStar: It's currently just being discussed on the Objective-C mailing list. You can read more about it [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). I have no idea when this latest version of clang will be available in Xcode but I'm guessing it will probably be pretty soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `NSMutableArray` and assign `NSMutableArray`s to it as its objects.

For example:

```
NSMutableArray * myBig2dArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// first internal array
NSMutableArray * internalElement = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
[internalElement addObject:@"First - First"];
[internalElement addObject:@"First - Second"];
[myBig2dArray addObject:internalElement];

// second internal array
internalElement = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
[internalElement addObject:@"Second - First"];
[internalElement addObject:@"Second - Second"];
[myBig2dArray addObject:internalElement];
```

Answer (score 3):

To make a 2 dimensional array you would make an array of arrays.

```
NSArray *2darray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", nil], NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"one_2", @"two_2", nil]];
```

It gets very verbose but that is the way I know how to do this. An array of dictionaries may be better for your situation depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an `NSMutableArray` wrapper for easy use as a Two Dimensional array. It is available on github as `CRL2DArray` here . https://github.com/tGilani/CRL2DArray

Comment: This would be a lot more useful if it provided a way to access the two dimensional array in a 1 dimensional way. Example: array{ {orange, pear} {red, blue, green} {square, circle} }  ..  array1D[3] = blue

Answer (score 0):

First you to have set An NSMutableDictionary on .h file

```
        @interface MSRCommonLogic : NSObject
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *twoDimensionArray;
        }

        then have to use following functions in .m file


        - (void)setValuesToArray :(int)rows cols:(int) col value:(id)value
        {
            if(!twoDimensionArray)
            {
                twoDimensionArray =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            }

            NSString *strKey=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dVs%d",rows,col];
            [twoDimensionArray setObject:value forKey:strKey];

        }

        - (id)getValueFromArray :(int)rows cols:(int) col
        {
            NSString *strKey=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dVs%d",rows,col];
            return  [twoDimensionArray valueForKey:strKey];
        }
```