# NSRegularExpression for an array of array?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsregularexpression

I have the following code:

```
//NSMutableArray sections - contains some data;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-c]" options:0 error:NULL];
    [sections enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * str, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * stop) {
        NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
        if (match)  {
            [filteredList addObject:match];
        }

}];
```

In this case sections is a `NSMutableArray`.

1. How should i change the code if sections would be an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArrays`?
2. If curently sections is a `NSMutableArray` how can I declare a `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArrays` of sections?

Comment: It looks like you want a two-dimensional array. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527521/how-to-produce-2-dimensional-array-in-objective-c for some examples.