# How to save two Arrays in two dimensional Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new at iOS Dev. I want to save two different arrays (`array1` & `array2`) in 2 dimensional array. I know how to save data directly in two dimensional array but can't by save two different arrays in one.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Aasvogel" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSArray* foo = [content componentsSeparatedByString: @","];

NSMutableArray *array1 = @[], *array2 = @[];
for ( int i = 0; i < [foo count]; i++ )
{
    NSString* day = foo[i];
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) { [array1 addObject:day];}
    else { [array2 addObject:day];}
}
// and here i have populated two arrays (array1 and array2)
// Now i want to save these arraya in below two dimensional array (dataArray) atIndex:0 and at Index:1


NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 2];
[dataArray addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"e",
                                                         @"el",
                                                         @"ale",
                                                         @"vela",
                                                         @"gavel",nil] atIndex:0];

[dataArray addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Represents 50 in Roman numeral",
                                                         @"Building Wing",
                                                         @"Pub Brew",
                                                         @"Thin Parchment or membranes",
                                                         @"chairperson's hammer",nil] atIndex:1];
```

Comment: Two arrays aren't enough to create a two-dimensional array.  I.e. `array1 + array2` is not `array1 * array2`.  Or is it simply `[dataArray addObject:array1]; [dataArray addObject:array2];`? Not really clear...

Comment: @trojanfoe but i am using it as a hardcode as you can see my second part of the code where i am assigning dataArray, i have populated the array with values.

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527521/how-to-produce-2-dimensional-array-in-objective-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638129/how-to-declare-a-two-dimensional-array-of-string-type-in-objective-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362740/creating-a-two-dimensional-array-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
NSArray * firstArray, *secondArray;
NSArray * mainArray= [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: firstArray, secondArray, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently implemented 2D array into my application. Please check below code which is available at [2DArray](https://github.com/tGilani/CRL2DArray)

```
int capacity;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *outerArray;

#define kCRL2DArrayEmptyKey @"kCRL2DArrayEmptyKey"

- (id) initWithRows:(int)x columns:(int)y
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        capacity = y;
        self.outerArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            NSMutableArray *innerArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                [innerArray addObject:kCRL2DArrayEmptyKey];
            }
            [self.outerArray addObject:innerArray];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about 2-dimensional array in iOS but if I were you I would be saved the two arrays within a dictionary such as

```
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [dict setvalue:yourArray forKey:@"FirstArray"];
 [dict setvalue:yourSecondArray forKey:@"SecondArray"];
```

And Use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no such thing as a two (or more) dimensional `NSArray`.  If you genuinely need an *n*-dimensional array object in iOS or OS X, you can of course roll your own, or you could instead create an `NSArray` of `NSArray` instances (which are columns and which are rows is entirely up to you).  In that case, you could e.g. add items by doing

```
[[outerArray objectAtIndex:0] addObject:@"Foo"];
[[outerArray objectAtIndex:1] addObject:@"Bar"];
```

That said, for the problem you are tackling, it looks to me as if an `NSDictionary` might be more appropriate, e.g. with keys `@"e", @"el"` and values `@"Represents 50 in Roman numerals", @"Building Wing"`.

If your concern is that the keys of `NSDictionary` are not held in sorted order, you can always extract the keys as an array and sort them.  Or, if the keys change regularly, you might want to use a more sophisticated approach (e.g. keeping a separate sorted array of keys and inserting them into the right place when adding to the `NSDictionary`).

Also, you know that in modern Objective-C you can write e.g.

```
@[ @"a", @"b", @"c" ]
```

or

```
@{ @"a": @1, @"b": 2 }
```

rather than the very verbose forms you're using above?

Answer (score 0):

this is how u add anything in a 2d array i.e an Array of arrays in objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *array 1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *array 2;

for(int col = 0;col <5;col++){

       array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         for(int row = 0;row<5;row++){

              [array2 addObject:myItems];

    }
       [array1 addObject:array2];

}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

use for loop to generate 2d array from 2 different array,
follow this stracture

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
    for(j = 0; j < ncolumns; j++)
        array[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

May be it will help you

Comment: -1: he is using an array of NSString NOT primitive data type. Futhermore you haven't written anything about array, and whole code looks like from taken from C code.